# Doctrine caching

Tags: caching, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am working o a big DB driven application that sometimes needs a huge data import. Data is imported from excel spreadsheets and at the start of the proces (for about 500 rows) the data is processed relatively quicly, but lates slows down significantly. Import generates 6 linked entites per row of excel that are flushed after processing every line. My guess is that all those entities are getting cached by doctrine and just build up. My idea is to clear out all that cach every 200 rows but I could not find how to clear it from within the code (console is not an option at this stage). Any assistance or links would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the cause may lie not in Doctrine but in the database [transaction log buffer size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_buffer_size). The documentation says

> A large log buffer enables large transactions to run without a need to write the log to disk before the transactions commit. Thus, if you have big transactions, making the log buffer larger saves disk I/O.

Most likely you insert your data in one big transaction. When the buffer is full, it is written to disk which is normally slower.

There are several possible solutions.

- Increase buffer size so that the transaction fits into the buffer.
- Split the transaction into several parts that fit into the buffer.

In the second case keep in mind that each transaction needs time as well, so wrapping each insert in a separate transaction will reduce performance as well.

I recommend to wrap about 500 rows in a transaction because this seems to be a size that fits in the buffer.

Comment: Did you check if this helps?